# simple_salesforce Custom Domain

Tags: login, login-errors, simple-salesforce

I am having some trouble using `simple_salesforce` to login using my username, password, security token. My companies SF instance is on a custom domain (I do not use [login.salesforce.com](https://login.salesforce.com/) and instead I enter custom domain which redirects me to login.COMPANY.com and then redirects back to XX.my.salesforce.com.

I have tried using

```
sf = Salesforce(username='username@company.com', password='password', security_token='XXXXXXXX')
```

but that did not work. I tried adding in `domain='ZZ'` but that did not work either. Does simple_salesforce support custom domains?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130278/python-simple-salesforce

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130278/python-simple-salesforce doesn't work with custom domains.